# display javascript prototype chain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I want to see the list of items in the prototype chain
Is there a way to know it?
I try to use getOwnPropertyNames, but it doesn't display the prototype chain

```
function Grid(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}
Grid.prototype.example = function() {console.log("hello");}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Grid()));
//["width", "length"]
```

why it doesn't show and is there a way to display it?

also I have a weird error when I use getOwnPropertyNames when the property inherited from another constructor

```
function Grid(width, height) {
  this.space = new Array(width * height);
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
}

console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Grid()));
//it gives me these errors
Uncaught RangeError: Invalid array length
at new Grid (<anonymous>:3:20)
at <anonymous>:2:40
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:905:140)
at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:838:34)
at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

why is that?

Comment: *"why is that?"* Because you are calling `new Array(NaN)` which is invalid. It has nothing to do with `getOwnPropertyNames` and all with you not passing the required arguments to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the simplest way is to use a `for` loop:

```
for (var prop in obj) {
  console.log(prop);
}
```

If you want to get all properties, not only the enumerable ones, you can use a combination of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` and [**`Object.getPrototypeOf`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf):

```
function getPropertyNames(obj) {
  return obj ? 
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
      .concat(getPropertyNames(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj))) :
    [];
}
```

Note: This list can contain duplicates.

Comment: whoaa, thannks, it works perfectly, it even display the rest of the prototype chains
how do I accept this as an answer? Can you please vote up my question, so I can gain reputation? thanks

Comment: @Salis: *"how do I accept this as an answer"* http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work